# Change directory to which SWT extracts its native libraries

Tags: java, swt

I noticed that SWT extracts its native libraries into a folder named `.swt` under my home directory. Is there any way I can specify a different directory?

Comment: Which OS? Which version of Java?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I noticed this on Windows XP and Ubuntu. SWT 3.7, Java 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the system property `swt.library.path` ([see the source](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/swt/internal/Library.java.htm), line 193).

Comment: Looks like I have to extract the required libraries by hand into the folder specified by `swt.library.path` before I can use this property.